# Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose that $x,y,z$ are positive integers satisfying $x \le y \le z$, and such that the product of all three numbers is twice their sum. What is the sum of all possible values of $z$?

Since this is for only positive integers, and there are sums and products involved, I think that this can be approached using Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick. I am not sure how though. Help is greatly appreciated

For those who do not know what Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick is, it is a method of factoring by grouping. For example, say that we want to factor $xy+x+y+1$. We can factor this as so:
$$xy+x+y+1$$
$$x(y+1)+y+1$$
$$x(y+1)+1(y+1)$$
$$(x+1)(y+1)$$

Comment: Without forcing the reader to search the Google for themselves, can you please tell us what "Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick" means?

Comment: It certainly works for $x=1$.  Then $yz-2y-2z=2,$ so $(y-2)(z-2)=6,$ and $(y,z)\in\{(3,8),(4,5)\}$

Comment: Also for $x=2$ the same trick gives $y=2,z=4$ as the only solution, but it doesn't work for $x=3.$  I wonder if there are any solutions with $3\le x\le y\le z?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x,y,z$ are positive integers, with $x \le y \le z$, such that $xyz=2(x+y+z)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&xyz=2(x+y+z)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&xyz \le 2(3z)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&xy \le 6\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2 \le 6\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \le 2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Consider two cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;x=1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&xyz=2(x+y+z)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&yz =2(1+y+z)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&yz - 2y -2z  - 2 = 0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(y-2)(z-2)=6
\end{align*}
which leads to a small number of possibilities for $y,z$, left for you to complete.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;x=2$.

Since $xy\le 6$, and $x \le y$, we get $2\le y\le 3$.

Using $x=2$, for each of $y=2,y=3$, solve the equation $xyz=2(x+y+z)$ for $z$.

Comment: If $x=2$ then $2yz=xyz=2(x+y+z)=2(2+y+z)$ so $yz=2+y+z$ so $(y-1)(z-1)=3$  with $2=x\leq y\leq z.$...........+1

Comment: Yes, that works well. I saw that move, but decided to exploit the inequality $xy\le 6$ instead, since it left only two possible values for $y$.